# Group analysis in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure

I have a data set, and I would like to produce a prediction model based on that data-set, usimg Microsoft Azure
This data-set contains some group of events that together make a bigger event, for example - few lines in the data-set that are close in time (there is a time column) create together one event in time.
does anybody know the method for how can I do it? is there anyway to create a prediction model that learns not from a certain column, but from a different data-set (of results, for that matter)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this does exist using [Azure Machine Learning](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/machine-learning/), have a look in the [Gallery](http://gallery.azureml.net/) for various examples where this has been shown.

I think for your specific question it will be good to have a look at the [Bike regression example](http://gallery.azureml.net/Experiment/d92ab449519a46be9b8f31776c1e638b). In that example they show how they aggregate information from multiple rows to score on a single feature.